# Difference between baseline of empty and non-empty inline blocks

Tags: css

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #aef;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
base <div>×</div> <div></div> line
```

The empty inline block is aligned differently from the one containing text. This can be fixed by specifying a different `vertical-align` value, but I wonder why this is happening. Can you point to a relevant part of CSS specification?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [CSS2: Line height calculations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visudet.html#line-height)

> **vertical-align: baseline** — align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box doesn't have a baseline, align
>   the bottom of the box with the parent's baseline.

Comment: This is what I was talking about. So, you have to use a parent element to set their children's alignment. Now you're aligning your parent element's content. Sigh.

Comment: @tuze consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rKaXH/ as you can see no parent elements are needed to set alignment.

Comment: You're still comparing void elements with normal elements. There are some differences between them. For example, void elements are displayed inline by default. But they can have width or height property seperatly from normal inline elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements

Comment: Content defination can only be used for normal elements. I hope It's clear know. Void elements are self-content in other meaning.

Comment: @tuze It works just as well for inline blocks: http://jsfiddle.net/4RqCe/ Maybe we're talking about different things, vertical-align has a special use for table cells, in that case it's indeed should be specified on parent element: http://jsfiddle.net/U2abT/