# inline-block with empty content makes layout disordered (vertical alignment)?

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

I'm working some css and encountered a weird problem. Two elements are `inline-block` staying in the same container. Both of them have the `width`, `height`, and `line-height`.

But if we set the first element an empty content, the layout will be disordered (vertical alignment).

You can see the problem [here](http://codepen.io/flanker/pen/dBFEf)

```
<div class="part">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
</div>

.part {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

I know empty content is always a bad smell of html code. But I just want to know why this is and how to solve this problem.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885873/vertical-alignment-of-empty-inline-block-elements). People say we could use a `&nbsp` instead of empty content. Is this the only way we could solve it? Or we have other better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'vertical-align: middle;' to the inline-block element

`vertical-align: middle;`

http://jsbin.com/ajexab/1/edit

Comment: Thanks mate. But do you know why empty content causes the layout disordered? 多谢 :)

Comment: default is vertical-align: baseline,  Here is a detailed explanation [difference-between-baseline-of-empty-and-non-empty-inline-blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215638/difference-between-baseline-of-empty-and-non-empty-inline-blocks)