# Why does increasing height of div move div down?

Tags: html, css

[The code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BQyVxg?editors=1100)

I'm making a grid of names out of divs, and to start off I made some fixed width boxes. Here's the relevant HTML:

```css
    
    #names {
        background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
        width:80%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .row {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
        height:80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .item{
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
        width:50px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="names">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="item">hi</div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For whatever reason, when there is text or an element in the divs, they are placed lower than if there is nothing inside them. In addition, the greater the `height` attribute is in `.item`, the farther down the divs are. This can be fixed with a negative `margin-top`, but it is likely to lead to problems in the future, and regardless I'd like to know the cause of this behavior.

Why is this happening? Why is it only happening with content inside the divs? Why does the height attribute have anything to do with it? Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried adding "hi" to both divs, and they both move **Up**. What now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between baseline of empty and non-empty inline blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215638/difference-between-baseline-of-empty-and-non-empty-inline-blocks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visudet.html#line-height:

> vertical-align: baseline — align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box doesn't have a baseline, align the bottom of the box with the parent's baseline.

Adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.item` should solve your problem. Also make sure to use `box-sizing: border-box;` to prevent the items to have a greater height than it's parent. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBNgWe

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but do you understand why the box moved down in the first place?

Comment: because an empty element has no baseline. so it falls back to `vertical-align: bottom;` as stated above and the element with text has a baseline so it will align itself with the baseline of the parent box. Aligning itself to the parents baseline means that the bottom of the text will be at the bottom of the parent (at least in this case).